# How to build a simple table filter with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, filter, jquery, jquery-effects

How can I build a simple table filter with good effect using jQuery? **I don't mind about pagination.**

> list -> select data of database.

**I do not want to use a plugin, I prefer the use of short code.**

Example:
[image: Table Filter With JQuery]

Comment: What do you mean with `Good Effect`? What do you have so far if you don't want plugins?

Comment: @pimvdb - Effect for `hide()`.I can not use the plugin, because my code the size is high.

Comment: I see but your question is a little broad. It does not differ much from a 'code this for me' question, which is not what Stack Overflow is for. You might want to show some code to get help for.

Comment: Example: http://www.andymatthews.net/code/tablefilter/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#inputFilter').keyup(function() {
    var that = this;
    $.each($('tr'),
    function(i, val) {
        if ($(val).text().indexOf($(that).val()) == -1) {
            $('tr').eq(i).hide();
        } else {
            $('tr').eq(i).show();
        }
    });
});
```

[***CHECH THIS***](http://jsfiddle.net/wY3Us/2/)

Comment: please give me `example` in http://jsfiddle.net. did this is for all `paginations`?

Comment: @Sheikhasa Mozali i gave you the fiddle. please check

Comment: why do disappear <th></th> ?

Comment: to prevent `<th>` from disappearing use `$("tbody tr")` as selector.. Also adding `toLowerCase()` to both strings would result in case insensitive filtering

Answer (score 3):

I don't normally help out with this, but I got bored this morning..

http://jsfiddle.net/hHJxP/

Answer (score 2):

I know it's kinda late but hope this code helps.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#yourInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#yourTableId tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try testing the innerHTML of the row to the value of the input field, showing / hiding the content depending on the test-result.

```
$('#test').bind('keyup', function() {
    var s = new RegExp(this.value);
    $('tr').each(function() {
        if(s.test(this.innerHTML)) $(this).show();
        else $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLeWZ/1/) with example table and input field.

**edit**

It might be better to use `.text()` instead of innerHTML. Performancewise innerHTML would be better, but `.text()` doesn't accept the html-tags as valid search results. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLeWZ/2/) #2.

Comment: if there is `pagination` this work for all dataes or only for same page of `pagination`?(i want work for `all page in pagination`) this is ok?

Comment: This will only work for the current table page. So if you're on page 5, only results on page 5 will be found and filtered.